# Is there a way to validate/authenticate the request and response for Msteams events and API's?

Tags: api, microsoft-teams, slack, rest

I am trying to validate whether the request for Msteams events and response for GRPAH API is from Msteams or not. Is there a way to validate/authenticate the request and response for MSteams.

For example : We can verify the request from Slack using the signing secret.
https://api.slack.com/authentication/verifying-requests-from-slack . Do we have a similar verification in Msteams.

Comment: Hi @deeptha, could you please explain which API you are using and could you please explain bit more to mitigate the issue.

Comment: I would like to validate the events are directed from the Msteams endpoint. Is there a way to validate it? And in general, all the possible API's in Msteams.

Answer (score 0):

We have [Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample), [Tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements), [Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) and [Security requirements for actionable messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/security-requirements#verifying-that-requests-come-from-microsoft) to validate/authenticate the request and response for MSteams.